# Deleting pointers from an array

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++, and this problem I am having has had me stumped for like the last 2 hours.  What I am trying to do is create an array of pointers to my class Word objects, so a 2 dimensional array, which is `**wordPtrList`. Then I need to delete the memory of certain objects in the array and set their pointers to null. I have written a smaller version of what I am trying to accomplish below.

```
int main()
{
    char *cArray;
    cArray = new char[4];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cArray[i] = 'a';

    cArray[i + 1] = '\0';   //cArray is a null terminated string

    Word **wordPtrList;
    wordPtrList = new Word* [3];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        wordPtrList[i] = new Word(cArray);
    }

    wordPtrList[1]->del();
    delete wordPtrList[1];
    wordPtrList[1] = '\0';

    return 0;
}

class Word
{
private:
    char* ptr_;
    int len_;
public:
    Word(const char* word)
    {
        len_ = strlen(word);
        ptr_ = new char[len_];      
        strcpy(ptr_, word);
    }
    ~Word()
    {
        delete [] ptr_;
        ptr_ = 0;
    }


    void del()
    {
        delete [] ptr_;
        ptr_ = 0;
        return;
    }

};
```

When I do this however, I get:

> Debug Error Heap Corruption Detected after normal block

This is in VS 2010 on Windows 7.

So what I am asking is, how do I delete the memory of my object so that I can set `wordPtrList[1]` to Null?

Comment: Hi. First thing I noticed: cArray[i + 1] = '\0'; i+1 equals 4, which is beyond the limit

Comment: @A.J. is right. Your second problem is that strlen returns the length of the string excluding the null byte. That means you have to add +1 to your `new` call

Comment: Ok yea, I see both of these now.  Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cArray[i] = 'a';
cArray[i + 1] = '\0';   //cArray is a null terminated string
```

The problem is at the last line which is using `i+1` as index, which is  going out of range, as by the time the loop exits, the value of `i` is already `3`; that means `i+1` will become `4` which cannot be a valid index when you've allocated `cArray` as:

```
cArray = new char[4]; //taken from your code
```

The solution is this:

```
cArray[i] = '\0';   //Now, it is correct. Here i is equal to 3
```

That is, use `i` instead of `i+1`; Or simply use `3`.

---

In C++, you could [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) instead of manual loop, as:

```
std::fill(cArray, cArray + 4, 'a'); //done
```

Even better avoid using `char*` with `new` as much as possible, and prefer using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating 4 bytes to cArray (meaning you have access to write to bytes 0 through 3), and then writing to cArray[4].  You also allocate one byte too small in the Word constructor.

```
char *cArray;
cArray = new char[4];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cArray[i] = 'a';
cArray[i] = '\0';   //cArray is a null terminated string - i is now 3
```

and

```
 Word(const char* word)
 {
    len_ = strlen(word);
    ptr_ = new char[len_ + 1];      
    strcpy(ptr_, word);
 }
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious off-by-one errors in the code (when you get out of the first loop what is the value of the variable `i`? when calling `strlen` did you remember to consider the space needed by the null terminator?).

Also please note that c strings are not "null terminated", they are "NUL terminated" with uppercase letters and only one "L". `NUL` is the name of the ASCII control character with all bits set to zero and is represented in C++ with `'\0'`.
In one place you used `NUL` character as a null pointer, and while this is technically correct (because of a design bug of the C++ language) it's better to understand that the two concepts are quite different.

Comment: I am slightly confused by this.  What exactly are the differences between NUL and '\0'?

Comment: There is no conceptual difference between `NUL` and `'\0'`, the first is the official ASCII name and the second is how you write it in a C++ program. The difference is between `NULL` (the "null pointer") and `'\0'`. In your code after deleting the class you are assigning `'\0'` to the pointer and this is conceptually wrong. Unfortunately because of a design bug in the C++ language itself the `NUL` character can be used as null pointer so the compiler will not complain and the code is formally correct. It's important you understand the difference however.

Comment: Oh ok, I am not sure why I set it equal to '\0' there.  So then when you are done using a pointer, would you want to set it equal NULL like ptr = NULL;  Also is this the same as ptr = 0?  Sorry for all of the questions.

Comment: @pistolpete333: Yes. Using `ptr=NULL;` is the same as using `ptr=0;`. The first makes more evident that the variable being set is a pointer so should be preferred (but I've to admit that I'm used to type `0` instead). Even if it's more typing remember that code is often written once and read many times over the lifespan of a program, so investing some writing time to ease reading phase is a good thing. Using `'\0'` is instead a no-no ... like I said it works but just because of a "bug" of the C++ language. Technically you can use also `ptr=3-2-1;` but you wouldn't do that, right? ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton for clearing that up for me.  I will definitely be aware of this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're basically accessing an array index which is out of bounds of the array.

I would go with Nathan Wiebe's solution.

In the future, when you have the option to do this, it's recommended to use `std::vector<T>` as that will allow you to store any type you wish in a dynamically resizeble array. In other words, providing you don't access an index which is outside of the vector's bounds, you could do something like this:

```
std::vector< char* > str;

for( size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i )
{
   str.push_back( 'a pointer to a block of memory consisting of characters' ); 
}

class Word
{
public:
    Word( const char* str )
    {
        mStrs.push_back( str );
    }
    ~Word( void )
     {
         for( size_t i = 0; i < mStrs.size(); ++i )
         {
             if( mStrs[ i ] )
             {
                 delete mStrs[ i ];
                 mStrs[ i ] = NULL;
             }
         }

         mStrs.clear();
     }

private:
    void del( size_t index )
    {   
         if( index > mStrs.size() )
         {
              //error - throw new exception or something
         }

         delete mStrs[ index ];
    }

    std::vector< const char* > mStrs;

};
```

Comment: Believe me, I would love to use vectors, but it was required we use character arrays for this hw assignment.  Are there any advantages to using character arrays vs vectors?

Comment: It depends. IF you're allocating a single string and you need that, it's better to use std::string, but if you need to use a char*, then a char* makes more sense as opposed to a vector *provided you know what you're doing*.

A great reference on C++ would the following faq, as well as this article in particular: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html